# How do I calculate my buck-boost converter's duty cycle value given a minimum input of ~0V?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTTqI.png]

I am trying to create a buck-boost converter to convert the 9V from my battery to 5V. I am following a textbook to do so and it says first to calculate the Duty Cycle Value based on the minimum and maximum input voltage.

Since: Vs(min) = <0.1V, Vs(max) = 9V

How do I calculate the duty cycle value? Substituting into the equation gives the unexpected result of 100%.

Comment: What current do you expect to be available at <0.1 V?

Answer (score 1):

> *buck-boost converter's duty cycle value given a
> minimum input of ~0V?*

and

> *Since: Vs(min) = <0.1V, Vs(max) = 9V*

If your input supply is 0 volts then no matter what you try, it won't work. Electronics need some voltage before they operate and, even the best power converters need at least around 0.8 volts to start-up without glitching or stalling. A lot of low voltage converters won't work below 2.5 volts as an input power supply.

So, it's a case of being reasonable and not expecting miracles to happen. I mean if your output (5 volts) powers a load of 1 amp then, a 1 volt supply would need to muster more than 5 amps just to do the conversion. That's 50 amps with an input supply of 0.1 volts!!